# Once Upon a Time in West the telegraph scene

Tags: once-upon-a-time-in-the-west

Is it possible to translate the telegraph message at the beginning of the film or is it just random noise?

I made a recording and passed it through sound analyser Audacity and I didn't see a pattern but maybe it takes a professional telegraphist to see it.

[image]

Comment: Well done people for making a new contributor feel welcome - downvoting both their first two questions.  Applause.

Comment: Pete - I'm sorry - there are some grumpy people here who downvote at the drop of a hat.  You're being penalized because in their eyes they don't see why it's interesting to know the answer to this.   In particular the question about the year that the movie is set could significantly affect your understanding of what is happening in the wider context of the story.

Comment: It's Morse code, right? Try looking up the Morse code table, then try to match the peaks in that sound wave to the characters in the table. A bit painstaking but not complicated I reckon.

Comment: Morse code is interpreted by _listening_ to the tones (or watching it in the case of signal lights). It takes practice, especially to decipher the code at the sort of speeds an experienced operator would send the signal.

Comment: Admittedly, my knowledge of morse itself is almost nil - however, the machine is a tickertape machine, meaning that you can't really tell the difference between a dot & a dash unless you read the tape; it was not really designed for 'live' decoding. Perhaps if you were right in front of it you could hear the 'tapper' return & judge the length from that, but really the tap is considerably louder than the release, so all you are hearing are "events" you can't really tell which is dot & which is dash. Possibly a morse expert could 'read' it, but I can't find anything online that would decipher it

Comment: It might be possible to distinguish between dots and dashes of the Morse code by listening to the difference in time between taps. Maybe you can even hear slightly longer pauses between groups of taps that represent characters and it seems you can clearly hear even longer pauses between words. Anyway, I would listen to the recordings at half the speed or less.

Answer (score 3):

it is in morse code, the whole message is:

.-- . .-.. -.-. --- --. ..- --. .... - ..--- ..-. .-.. .- --. ... - --- -. ... . ...-- --- ...- . .-..- ..-. .-. --- --. ....- ..-. .-.. --- --. -... --- .-. -. .----. ...-- --- ...- .-.. .-..

I hope I am not making too many mistakes,

"Welcome to Flagstone. This is from overseas. Request immediate reply. There are two killers headed your way. They are killing everybody/have killed everyone. Please forward this message to Rock Point."

Comment: Wow, that's great if it's correct. It makes total sense in the scene. How did you work it out?

Comment: There are not enough characters in the morse to make a sentence that long without major abbreviations. What is the literal morse message in text?

Comment: Your code says "welcogmght7flagstonse3ove?frog4flogbo13ovll". Is that what you meant?

Comment: in my opinion this doesnt invalidate your answer. Probably there was no actual message.